# twitter share button and google map location not showing on apk

Tags: javascript, java, html, cordova, apk

I have a problem I am creating a Cordova project to run on android phone/android emulator. So while developing the project am using Cordova serve and testing it on the google chrome browser and all is working fine. But when I try to run on the emulator or when I build the APK to run on Android devices, two functions is not working.

No 1. The Twitter share button is not working.
No 2. The Google map API for autocomplete address and to view it on map is not working

Why is it like that on emulator and Android phone? But it's working on Cordova serve google chrome browser.

```js
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
            var tblText='<section id="pricePlans">';
            var len = results.rows.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var tmpArgs=results.rows.item(i).UserId + ",'" + results.rows.item(i).FirstName
                        + "','" + results.rows.item(i).LastName+"','" + results.rows.item(i).Location+"','" + results.rows.item(i).aDate+"','" + results.rows.item(i).Time+"', '" + results.rows.item(i).Report+"'";
                tblText +='<ul id="plans"><li class="plan"><ul class="planContainer"><li class="title1"><h3>'
                        + results.rows.item(i).FirstName +'</h3></li><li><ul class="options"><li align="center"><span>REPORTER:</span> ' + results.rows.item(i).LastName +'</li><li align="center"><span>LOCATION:</span> ' + results.rows.item(i).Location +'</li><li align="center"><span>DATE:</span> ' + results.rows.item(i).aDate +'</li><li align="center"><span>TIME:</span> ' + results.rows.item(i).Time +'</li><li align="center"><span>REPORT:</span> ' + results.rows.item(i).Report +'</li></ul></li><li class="button"><a href="#" onclick="goPopup('+ tmpArgs + ');">Manage</a></li><li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+ results.rows.item(i).FirstName +'%20at%20' + results.rows.item(i).Location +'%20on the%20' + results.rows.item(i).aDate +'%20at%20'+ results.rows.item(i).Time +'%20by%20' + results.rows.item(i).LastName +'"><img alt="tweet" src="img/1.png" width="90" height="35"></a></li><li><iframe width="220" height="220" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=AIzaSyC0SH9RFJ9pgJQXeY75hjXG07iLBHgVBZA&origin='+ results.rows.item(i).Location +'&destination='+ results.rows.item(i).Location +'"</iframe></li></ul></li></ul>';
            }
            tblText +="</section>";
            document.getElementById("tblDiv").innerHTML =tblText;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC0SH9RFJ9pgJQXeY75hjXG07iLBHgVBZA&libraries=places"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', intilize);
   function intilize(){
   
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txLocation'));
   
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function(){
    
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var location = place.formatted_address + "<br/>";
    var endlat = place.geometry.location.lat() + "<br/>";
    var endlong = place.geometry.location.lng();
   });
  };
  </script>
```